# Java Modify text file content from Jtextfiields as input

Tags: java, swing

Currently I get stuck in the modification parts. I having a "booklist.txt":

aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd

qqq-www-eee-rrr

```
    String q=oldID.getText();
    String w=newID.getText();
    String a=Author.getText();
    String r=title.getText();
    String t=quantity.getText();
            try{
    File f= new File("BookList.txt");
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f);
    String line=br.readLine();
    String oldtext="";
    String newtext="";
    String[] tem=new String[4];

    while(line!=null)
    {
    oldtext +=line+System.getProperty("line Seperator");
    tem=line.split("-");
    if(tem[0].equals(q)){
            newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(line,w+"-"+e+"-"+r+"-"+t);
            }     
    }
    fw.write(newtext);        
    fw.close();
    br.close();
            }catch(IOException Ex){Ex.printStackTrace();}
```

What i want is get input from the Jtexfields and replace the strings in the text file.

Example:
if the id that I type is qqq(tem[0]) then the while loop will read all the line in text file.If the qqq that i type is found, modify the other strings which is www, eee, and rrr. The input to replace these strings are from the Jtextfields (String q,w,e,r,t)

Comment: where you are defining jtextfield ?

Answer (score 0):

in order to write in a file use **FileWriter**!

here is what should you do

```
FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(path);
writer.writeln(newText);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

this will create a file even if the file path doesn't exist.
Be aware this will remove all content in the file and the content will be replaced. However if you don't want to replace the content add a parameter to FileWriter object to be like this

```
new FileWriter(path,true);
```

this will append the current content with the new content you want to add

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure if that what is you need
First thing you have to read the whole file
the second step you need to put the whole lines into ArrayList due arrayList is dynamic array

finally do your compare

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File(path));
ArrayList<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){list.add(scanner.nextLine())}
```

finally for example you want to replace something let us assume QQQ as you mention

```
if(list.contains("QQQ"))
{
list.replace("QQ",myNewText)>0
}else list.add(myNewText);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but my question is If the oldID that I type in theJtextfield match to the ID in the textfile, then how to modify the line that i get from the Jtextfields as input..

Comment: so do you want to compare two strings with each other ?

Comment: ya i want to compare two strings which is the id that i type and the id in the text file. If the two id match, modify the strings belong to the line